# How to fetch details from NSData

Tags: iphone, ios, ios5, nsdata

I want to fetch specified data `html_instructions` from the below URL. I could take all data from this [URL](http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?%20origin=Chennai&destination=Madurai&sensor=false).

But I need the specific `html_instructions` only. How can I split the data?

I used the following code to convert the URL to NSData:

```
 NSString *url = [NSString      stringWithFormat:@"http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin=Chennai&destination=Madurai&sensor=false"];
    NSURL *googleRequestURL=[NSURL URLWithString:url];
    dispatch_async(kBgQueue, ^{
    NSData* data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL: googleRequestURL];
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I parsed the json from the following url and printed the html instructions try copy this code and try: 
http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin=Toronto&destination=Montreal&sensor=false

```
   NSData *receivedData = Received data from url;
   NSError* error;
   NSMutableDictionary* parsedJson = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:receiveData              options:kNilOptions  error:&error];

           NSArray *allkeys = [parsedJson allKeys];

        for(int i = 0; i < allkeys.count; i++){
            NSLog(@"############################");
            if([[allkeys objectAtIndex:i] isEqualToString:@"routes"]){
                NSArray *arr        = [responseJsonValue objectForKey:@"routes"];
                NSDictionary *dic   = [arr objectAtIndex:0];
                NSLog(@"ALL KEYS FROM ROUTE: %@", [dic allKeys]);
                NSArray *legs = [dic objectForKey:@"legs"];
                  NSLog(@"legs array count %d", legs.count);
                for(int i = 0;  i < legs.count; i++){
                    NSArray *stepsArr = [[legs objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"steps"];
                    for (int i = 0; i < stepsArr.count; i++) {
                        NSLog(@"HTML INSTRUCTION %@", [[stepsArr objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"html_instructions"]);
                    }
                }

            }
            NSLog(@"############################");
        }
```

Comment: sorry to disturb you. i gave "html_instructions" in the place "YOURKEY". but it display null.

Comment: Can u post the parsedJson? Which is null?

Comment: sorry  it is my testing variable so replace it by parsedJson

Comment: Thank you so much jailani. i cant control my happy because of you only. thanks a lot,thanks.

Comment: jailani how i store this value in table.please help me.

Comment: Do you want to store and use html instruction? If yes why don't you use mutable array to store the html instructions?

Comment: i used array like below and I used both method numberOfRowsInSection and cellForRowAtIndexPath for table. but the table display null. How can I display?                                            NSMutableArray *array=[[stepsArr objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"html_instructions"] ;

Comment: in your viewcontroller.h add @property(nonatomic, retain)NSArray * stepsArr;  in viewController.m add @synthesize stepsArr;  replace the line NSArray *stepsArr = [[legs objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"steps"];  by self.stepsArr = [[legs objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"steps"]; and try it...

Comment: no value display in table.array having value so i think table can't retrieve the value. please help me jailani.vishnusivabalan.sp@gmail.com this is my mail id.

Comment: soory i can't get you,jailani.

Answer (score 2):

Use this as :

```
    NSData* data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:googleRequestURL];
    if (data == nil) {
        return;
    }
    NSError* error;
    NSMutableDictionary* json = [NSJSONSerialization
                                 JSONObjectWithData:data

                                 options:kNilOptions
                                 error:&error];

    NSLog(@"Json : %@",json);
```

Hope it helps you.

Comment: thanks for your rply nishant. but Json also display all data from URL. in need specified "html_instructions" data only from URl.thanks